# What is a good example of recursion other than generating a Fibonacci sequence?

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, fibonacci

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Real-world examples of recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105838/real-world-examples-of-recursion)
>   [Examples of Recursive functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126756/examples-of-recursive-functions)

I see that most programming language tutorial teach recursion by using a simple example which is how to generate fibonacci sequence, my question is, is there another good example other than generating fibonacci sequence to explain how recursion works?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105838/real-world-examples-of-recursion

Comment: Fibonacci really isn't a 'good example of recursion'.

Comment: Also duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/126756/examples-of-recursive-functions. (Well, unlike this one, that question isn't tagged C++. But I doubt that is relevant for understanding recursion.)

Comment: @Nabb: Why not? I think it’s a *phenomenal* example because it’s amenable to so many smart optimizations and it can serve to explain not only vanilla recursion but also memoization and dynamic programming.

Comment: It's weird how these `"Hey, give me an example of ____."` questions get so many votes.

Comment: @Konrad: It's not really a good example because recursion doesn't help much here.  In order to calculate fib(x) sans optimization, you need fib(x-1) and fib(x-2), and to calculate fib(x-2) you need the two before that, and so on all the way back to fib(0) and fib(1).  So you're eventually calculating them all anyway.  An iterative solution could "memoize" just as well (by keeping a list/array with a "last calculated" index, and calculating from there up to x as needed), leaving no real benefits for recursion -- and removing the worries about having enough stack space.

Comment: @cHao But the recursive version is conceptually much simpler, which is *the* main advantage of recursion over iteration. This is already illustrated by the fact that the “natural” definition of the Fibonacci numbers *is* recursive, not iterative. … Give me a recursive Fibonacci implementation over an iterative one any day.

Comment: It is weird. If people are voting to reopen because of the C++ tag, the top voted answer is in python!

Comment: Locked. I think we have enough examples now, in this question *and* the duplicate ones.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The classic is the binary tree search:

```
def findval (node,val):
    if node == null:
        return null
    if node.val = val:
        return node
    if node.val > val:
        return findval (node.left,val)
    return findval (node.right,val)

findval (root,thing_to_find)
```

That may be a little more complex than a simple formula but it's the "bread and butter" use of recursion, and it illustrates the best places to use it, that where the recursion levels are minimised.

By that I mean: you *could* add two non-negative numbers with:

```
def add (a,b):
    if b == 0:
        return a
    return add (a+1,b-1)
```

but you'd find yourself running out of stack space pretty quickly for large numbers (unless the compiler optimised tail-end recursions of course, but you should probably ignore that for the level of teaching you're concerned with).

Comment: is the side note about going out of stack space a bait to revive the python Tail-end recursion troll ? That's definitely a python issue...

Comment: No, although that _looks_ like Python, it's really pseudo-code (I find Python a very good template for pseudo-code). I was just stating that, if the compiler didn't perform tail-end optimisation, you need to control the stack levels pretty tightly, lest you run out.

Comment: My fav is :: **If you found a good example then you are done otherwise search for example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945128/what-is-a-good-example-of-recursion-other-than-generating-a-fibonacci-sequence)**

Answer (score 29):

The other answers mention various algorithms, which is completely fine, but if you want a bit more "concrete" example, you could list all files in some directory and its subdirectories. The hierarchical file system is a well-known example of a recursive (tree) structure, and you could show depth-first and breadth-first search using this concrete example.

Comment: +1.  Missed this answer until after I had also supplied the same answer.  I've added sample code

Answer (score 27):

My favourite example for recursion is the [Towers of Hanoi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi#Recursive_solution): To move a stack of pieces from pole A to pole B, you move everything above the lowest piece to the pole that is not A or B, then move the lowest piece to B, and then you move the stack that you put on the "helper pole" on top of the lowest piece. For the first and third step, you follow this instruction recursively. See the link for a longer explanation :)

Comment: +1. Also, ToH can be tweaked slightly to force you to think even more about the recursion at work; e.g., a ring can only move one pole at a time (no direct A->C), etc. Great practice for recursion!

Comment: I encountered this recently when reading through JavaScript the good parts. Took me about an hour of thinking and drawing on a whiteboard before I got it and realized what a neat algorithm it is. The difficult part was figuring out what subproblem the algorithm is solving when the parameters get switched around in recursive calls.

Answer (score 21):

Check for a [palyndrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindrome):

```
bool recursivePalindrome(std::string str, unsigned int index = 0) {
    if (index > str.length()/2) return true;
    else if (str[index] == str[str.length()-index-1])
        return recursivePalindrome(str, ++index);
    else return false;
}
```

Or on a less serious note  :)

```
void StackOverflow()
{
   StackOverflow();
}
```

Comment: Although a good tail-end optimiser will simply convert that to `while(1);` :-)

Comment: Doing palindromes non-recursively would seem a *lot* easier, though: `unsigned last = str.size() - 1; while (index < last) if (str[index++] != str[last--]) return false; return true;`.

Comment: This comes close to a palindrome and is more serious: `:(){ :|: & };:`.

Answer (score 16):

How about finding factorial.

```
int GetFactorial(int n )
{
  if ( n==0) return 1;
  return n*GetFactorial(n-1);
}
```

The idea is, factorial is defined recursively as the product of n and factorial of (n-1). And from recursive definition, you get your recursion.

Comment: Well, factorial isn't all that different from fibonacci, is it?

Comment: True, but it's different enough :)

Comment: @sbi Unlike fibonacci, calculating factorial recursively is the same big-O runtime as doing it the sensible iterative way, so it's definitely an improvement. On the other hand, it doesn't demonstrate multiple recursive calls.

Comment: @Nick: You do have a point there, although I still think that the two are quite similar. (Oh, and if you do the fibonacci using template-meta programming, that will avoid repeatedly calculating the same results. `:)` )

Answer (score 12):

Traversing the folder hierarchy of a directory tree as part of a file system is a good real-world example. Look into this SO post for a C++ example:

[Why am I having problems recursively deleting directories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468774/recursive-directory-deletion-with-win32)

Comment: +1 because you don't need to expend any brain power on understanding the use-case (unlike maths-based problems), so you can focus on just the recursion aspect.

Comment: +1. Some more examples (in Java): 1) [counting files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/126756/examples-of-recursive-functions/2765589#2765589), 2) [recursive deletion, straight from Guava library](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/src-html/com/google/common/io/Files.html#line.502)

Answer (score 10):

Merge sort is a pretty good example of an algorithm that is easier to read and understand when implemented recursively.

Here's a little high-level pseudocode version of Merge Sort:

```
def merge_sort(List sortlist)
    if sortlist.length <= 1 return sortlist
    split sortlist into leftlist and rightlist
    return merge(merge_sort(leftlist), merge_sort(rightlist))   

def merge(List leftlist, List rightlist)
    while(leftlist and rightlist not empty)
        compare leftlist.first to rightlist.first
        pop lowest value off its list and append to resultlist
    append any remains of leftlist onto resultlist
    append any remains of rightlist onto resultlist
    return resultlist
```

An iterative version of this is would be much more complicated to write and to visualise.

Comment: @back2dos: yep +1, quicksort is another good example. I thought mergesort might be slightly easier to understand in a tutorial situation, but they are basically quite similar.

Answer (score 10):

- Most of the other examples given here are mathematics examples which really just re-illustrate the same application of recursion.
- The search and sort variants are good algorithm examples but often a bit too complicated for   beginners.
- Towers of Hanoi is a classic but pretty contrived really.

================

The example I use for demonstrating the simple power of recursion is recursive file processing in a directory tree.

Here is a C# example

```
void ProcessFiles( string sFolder )
{
    foreach( string f in Directory.GetFiles( sFolder ) )
    {
        DoSomethingTo( f );
    }
    foreach( string d in Directory.GetDirectories( sFolder ))
    {
        ProcessFiles( d );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There are several samples:

[Catalan numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number):

```
T(n) = Sum(T(i)*T(n-i)) for all 1 <= i < n
```

[Ackermann function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AckermannFunction.html):

```
A(x,y) = y+1 (if x = 0)
A(x,y) = A(x-1,1) (if y=0)
A(x,y) = A(x-1, A(x,y-1)) otherwise.
```

[Simple Maze problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze)

[Finding Hamiltonian Path problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem)

factorial.

and you can see [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion) page for other references.

Comment: The Catalan numbers have a much more efficient iterative/tail-recursive form.

Comment: @Donal Fellows, Fibonacci numbers iterative algorithm is more powerful than  recursive one O(n) versus (O((1+sqrt(5))^n), and if you say you can use memoization, also you can use memoized recursive for catalan numbers.

Comment: Memoization is indeed applicable in all of those cases, but it's less vital in cases where there's a linear algorithm. It's the truly non-linear algorithms that really benefit though. (Plus, the *best* examples of recursion involve recursive structures such as filesystems or other types of tree.)

Answer (score 5):

Good examples of recursion are often related to cases where underlying data structure or the problem itself is recursive : trees, graphs, algorithms using divide and conquer approach (like many sorts), parser of recursive grammars (like common arithmetic expresions), find strategy for chess-like two players games (for a simple exemple consider Nim), combinatory problems, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Try recursive binary search:
http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-cpp/algorithms/searching/rbinarysearch.html

Or a recursive quick sort:
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/72311-recursive-quicksort-algorithm/

These are just two small example in a vast world of recursive functions.

Answer (score 3):

Evaluation of arithmetic expressions can be done recursively or iteratively using a stack. It can be quite instructive to compare the two approaches.

Answer (score 2):

I remember that I *understood* recursion by writing a programm, that searches for  [word ladders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_ladder). In a given dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

My mother-in-law took an introductory course in C. She had a homework problem, something like:

> You have a bar of metal (length len), and a number
>   of orders (n) to cut the metal into
>   various lengths. You want to maximize
>   the amount of metal being used, but
>   cannot exceed the overall length.

The instructor suggested iterating from 1 to 2**n in binary, excluding an order if its corresponding bit were 0 and including an order if its bit were 1, while keeping track of the maximum sum. His proposal would run in polynomial time.

Another solution exists using a recursive [knapsack algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). You can iterate down from len to 1 and do a depth-first search to recursively find the sum of lengths.

A different area in which I have used recursion was for [Huffman coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) (for compressing a string), but this does not have the intuitive feel of the knapsack problem.

Recursion is a wonderful concept that is radically different. Best wishes in learning or teaching it.

Answer (score 1):

Ackermann function:

```
/* undefined if m and n are negative */
uint32 ackermann( uint32 m, uint32 n )
{
  if( m < 0 && n < 0 ) { exit(1); /* invalid m and n */ }

  if( m == 0 ){ return n + 1; }

  if( m > 0 && n == 0 ){ return ackermann( m - 1, 1 ); }

  if( m > 0 && n > 0 ){ return ackermann( m - 1, ackermann(m, n - 1) ); }
}
```

The multiple comparisons of m > 0 are redundant (and can be simplified). Leaving them as-is, however, shows the standard definition of the Ackermann function.

But one does not have to go so far off the mathematical edge to find interesting recursive functions other than the Fibonnaci numbers.

You have the greatest common denominator (GDC) function, quicksort and the always typical binary search algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Anything which has a hierarchy.
For example listing all the employees beneath your boss.

Answer (score 1):

Recursion finds its fundations in mathematical induction, and should be taught as such.

Defining functions by induction can be exposed clearly with list processing. There are many things to say about [`fold`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29) for instance.

Then, move on to trees.

Answer (score 1):

It's not C++, obviously, but the concept is sound:

PHP recursively traversing nested multidimensional arrays:

```
public function recurse_me($collection) {
    foreach ($collection as $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $this->recurse_me($value);
        } else {
            // process value.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The academic example is the factorial

> n!

calculum.
In real life, you get math libs.

Comment: The factorial is good for describing _how_ recursion works. It is a bad example of _why_ you should use recursion (in languages like C++).

Comment: @Henk At least it's better than fibonacci. In functional languages, (tail-) recursively is how you'd calculate factorials!

Comment: @Nick: Actually, that's how you would calculate fibonacci numbers too.

Comment: @Donal Sure, but _loops_ are done tail-recursively in purely functional languages. Calculating Fibonacci "the recursive way" requires two recursive invocations, so you can't do it tail-recursively.

Comment: @Nick: Wrong, it requires a more sophisticated function (which can be wrapped). Here's an example in Erlang, but trivially translatable: http://en.literateprograms.org/Fibonacci_numbers_(Erlang)#Tail_recursive_fibonacci

Comment: @Donal That's just a functional formulation of the standard iterative approach to generating fibonacci numbers. The go-to example for demonstrating recursion, in contrast, requires two recursive calls, and thus can't be made purely tail recursive.

Comment: @Nick: There are plenty of functions that require recursion, and non-tail recursion at that (the Ackermann function, for example, or almost anything interesting with trees). It just happens that Fibonacci number calculation isn't one of them. Nor is factorial calculation.

Comment: @Donal I'm not arguing with that. But the canonical way to teach recursion, as mentioned by the OP, is a recursive formulation of Fibonacci. Reformulating it as tail-recursive in a functional language is missing the point.

Comment: @Nick: I think we're definitely wandering away from the point, which is to answer the question at the top! Tree traversal is definitely my pick for a good recursion example (you can do it non-recursively by using an auxiliary stack, but that's much less clear).

Comment: @Donal I concur entirely on that point - tree traversal is a much better example. I think the only reason they don't typically use it in courses is because they're generally trying to teach recursion before they teach about trees.

Comment: @Nick: Making it practical by using the filesystem is the best option. The students will have encountered that before.

Comment: @DonalFellows you're link is now broken.

Answer (score 0):

There are sorting algorithms that rely on recursion.

And then, there's the *binary search* that is implemented with recursion.

Comment: These are little bit complex to understand to explain recursion.

Comment: @Gunner, a well-written recursive binary search should be no more than ten lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

[Pascal's triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_triangle)

Answer (score 0):

Heap sort is also a good example. You can read about it in "Introduction to Algorithms" by Cormen, Rivest and others. Great book, I hope you'll find a lot of interesting there.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of operations on linked-node type structures can be recursive. Others have mentioned BSTs, but if you don't want to have to explain what those are, consider searching for the highest value in a linear, unsorted list:

```
int MaxValue(Node node)
{
    if (node == null)
        return 0;

    if (node.Next == null)
        return node.Value;

    int maxNext = MaxValue(node.Next);
    return node.Value > maxNext ? node.Value : maxNext;
}
```

Lists (in this case, linked lists) are very easy to explain in real-world terms; your audience doesn't even have to have a programming background. You can simply describe it as a group of unsorted boxes, or a list of numbers.